# Why does google maps AutocompleteService include Irish address in results even with restriction to "gb" only?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

The following code snippet still includes Irish address in the predictions even if I have restricted it to "gb" only. If I set input to be a different address outside the Great Britain such as "paris, france", the predictions will be null as expected. I'm not sure if I have set up anything wrong or it's just a bug of google's autocomplete service.

```
var service = new window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
var input = "dublin, ireland";

function callback (predictions, status) {
     console.log(predictions, status);
}

service.getPlacePredictions({
    input: input,
    types: ["geocode"],
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: "gb"
    }
}, callBack);
```

Updated:
I have filed the bug as xomena suggested.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112065348

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue with the place autocomplete web service request applying the same parameters

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=dublin%2C%20ireland&types=geocode&components=country%3AGB&key=MY_API_KEY`

As shown in the screenshot, indeed, of 5 items 1 is definitely located in Ireland and 4 in Northern Ireland

[image]

It seems to be error on Google side, because place ID ChIJAVEnPNX9XUgR-1f5T_Mzj6g should be filtered out by country filter.

I found this place on maps.google.com and it has Ireland as address component, so something is broken in the API:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Dublin+Road,+Mill+Creek,+Co.+Cavan,+Ireland/@53.8288516,-7.0884112,14.61z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x485dfdd53c275101:0xa88f33f34ff957fb!8m2!3d53.8338312!4d-7.0730227

Feel free to file bug for Google in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789006). Hopefully , Google will fix it soon.